# In Typescript unable to acess global function

Tags: typescript, cloudflare-workers

I am using cloudflare workers with miniflare. I have created a `bindings.d.ts` file:

```
export interface Bindings {
  ENV: string
  MYSQL_URL: string
  JWT_SECRET: string
  JWT_ACCESS_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
  JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DAYS: number
  JWT_RESET_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
  JWT_VERIFY_EMAIL_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
}

declare global {
  function getMiniflareBindings(): Bindings
}
```

In this file I have globally declared the function `getMiniflareBindings()`. In another file I access this by calling:

```
getMiniflareBindings()
```

But upon running my code I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: getMiniflareBindings is not defined
```

build.js:

```
import { build } from 'esbuild'

try {
  await build({
      entryPoints: ['./src/index.ts'],
      bundle: true,
      outdir: './dist/',
      sourcemap: true,
      minify: true
    })
} catch(err) {
  process.exitCode = 1;
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": [
      "@cloudflare/workers-types",
      "@types/bcryptjs"
    ]
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "bindings.d.ts"]
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

An update. In .bindings.d.ts I now declare it like so:

```
export interface Bindings {
  ENV: string
  JWT_SECRET: string
  JWT_ACCESS_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
  JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DAYS: number
  JWT_RESET_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
  JWT_VERIFY_EMAIL_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
  DATABASE_NAME: string
  DATABASE_USERNAME: string
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: string
  DATABASE_HOST: string
}

declare global {
  const ENV: string
  const JWT_SECRET: string
  const JWT_ACCESS_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
  const JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DAYS: number
  const JWT_RESET_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
  const JWT_VERIFY_EMAIL_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number
  const DATABASE_NAME: string
  const DATABASE_USERNAME: string
  const DATABASE_PASSWORD: string
  const DATABASE_HOST: string
}
```

And in my code I access the values directly:

```
const env = {
  ENV,
  DATABASE_NAME,
  DATABASE_USERNAME,
  DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  DATABASE_HOST,
  JWT_SECRET,
  JWT_ACCESS_EXPIRATION_MINUTES,
  JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DAYS,
  JWT_RESET_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_MINUTES,
  JWT_VERIFY_EMAIL_EXPIRATION_MINUTES
}
```

This works great in production and developing but testing is where I have the issue as none of these are "defined" when I run my tests and I am just stuck.

Comment: I just created an exact replica of your provided code locally, and it works perfectly fine (I only added a package.json with `esbuild` as a dependency, and put `getMiniflareBindings()` in src/index.ts)

Comment: Also, in the [official source code](https://github.com/cloudflare/miniflare/blob/07f312221bccb78aee3a8491a2975b13890b365b/packages/shared-test-environment/src/globals.ts#L52), it seems that getMiniflareBindings is typed globally. If you don't use the dependency directly, you can try to add the package and see if their typings work. If this works for you, let me know and I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: This is a [runtime error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) and not a TS compilation error. Changing your type definitions won't solve the problem. What dependencies do you have and what versions are they? Please [edit] that info into your post.

Comment: Do you have a github repo with this code in it? It'd be much easier to help if I could just git clone and start hacking away...

Answer (score 0):

You may miss testEnvironment in config file, please try to add below in your jest.config.js file.

```
  testEnvironment: "miniflare",
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. I hope it would help.**

```
interface Bindings {
     ENV: string;
     MYSQL_URL: string;
     JWT_SECRET: string;
     JWT_ACCESS_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number;
     JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DAYS: number;
     JWT_RESET_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number;
     JWT_VERIFY_EMAIL_EXPIRATION_MINUTES: number;
    }

export const getMiniFlareBindings = (): Bindings => {
  const ENV = process.env.ENV || 'development';
  const MYSQL_URL =
  process.env.MYSQL_URL || 'mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/miniflare';
  const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'secret';
  const JWT_ACCESS_EXPIRATION_MINUTES =
  process.env.JWT_ACCESS_EXPIRATION_MINUTES || 15;
  const JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DAYS =
  process.env.JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DAYS || 30;
  const JWT_RESET_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_MINUTES =
  process.env.JWT_RESET_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_MINUTES || 60;
  const JWT_VERIFY_EMAIL_EXPIRATION_MINUTES =
  process.env.JWT_VERIFY_EMAIL_EXPIRATION_MINUTES || 60;

  return <Bindings>{
    ENV,
    MYSQL_URL,
    JWT_SECRET,
    JWT_ACCESS_EXPIRATION_MINUTES,
    JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DAYS,
    JWT_RESET_PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_MINUTES,
    JWT_VERIFY_EMAIL_EXPIRATION_MINUTES,
   };
 };
```